# Write entered numbers in an excel file with each button click in C#

Tags: c#, excel

I want to make a win app which includes one `TextBox` and one `Button` 'add'. When user enters a number and clicks the button for the first time, program will create an excel file and then write numbers in order in this file with each click. 
Here is my buttonAdd:

```
private void buttonAdd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    double num1;

    Excel.Application xlApp;
    Excel.Workbook xlWorkBook;
    Excel.Worksheet xlWorkSheet;

    xlApp = new Excel.Application();
    xlWorkBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Add();
    xlWorkSheet = (Excel.Worksheet)xlWorkBook.ActiveSheet;

    num1 = Convert.ToDouble(textBox1.Text);

    xlWorkSheet.Cells[i, 1] = num1;
    i++;

    xlWorkBook.SaveAs(path);
    xlWorkBook.Close(true);
}
```

I know that his code does not work because in every button click, the program tries to a create new excel file with same path. I am new to object oriented programming so I don't know how I can create an excel file outside of the 'buttonAdd_Click' and call it inside the 'buttonAdd_Click'.

Is there anybody who has an idea about it?

Comment: @Mihai yes, I made it work and the answer is quite clear. Thank you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create your excel sheet outside your `buttonAdd_Click` function. Inside the function you only access your sheet.

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    // Declare a private member in your MainWindow
    Excel.Application xlApp;
    Excel.Workbook xlWorkBook;
    Excel.Worksheet xlWorkSheet;

    private void buttonAdd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Assign to our private member only once, at the first button click
        if (xlWorkSheet == null)
        {
            xlApp = new Excel.Application();
            xlWorkBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Add();
            xlWorkSheet = (Excel.Worksheet)xlWorkBook.ActiveSheet;
        }

        // After the second button click, we already have a reference 
        // to a work sheet, so we can just write to it.

        xlWorkSheet.Cells[1, 1] = 10; // Just an example.

        // DON'T close the excel application here.
    }
```

You can close your excel application when your main application closes and NOT after every time we write something to the sheet, as your current code does. You can use the [Window.Closing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.window.closing%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) event, for example.